# delay loop time calculation assembly

Tags: assembly, time, delay, cycle, nested-loops

i have just started learning assembly, and i'm implementing a basic delay subroutine using nested increment loops of A and HX (not allowed to use timers yet!).

here's my subroutine:

```
;delay subroutine:
delay                   ;delay label
  LDA #0                ;loads A with 0

loop_1                  ;first loop
  ADD #1                ;increments A
  LDHX #0               ;loads HX with 0

loop_2                  ;second loop
  AIX #1                ;increments HX
  CPHX number_2         ;compares HX to number_2
  BNE loop_2            ;loops if not equal

  CMP number_1          ;compares A to number_1
  BNE loop_1            ;loops if not equal

  RTS                   ;returns from delay sr
```

I'm trying to derive a formula to work out the number of cycles the routine takes to complete.

The out of loop cycles (JSR,LDA, RTS) sum to 12

The loop_1 cycles (ADD,LDHX,CMP,BNE) sum to 10

The loop_2 cycles (AIX,CPHX,BNE) sum to 8

I'm thinking that I would need some kind of recursive sum as a function of number_1 and number_2 to work this out. Ideally I would like to work backwards to solve for number_2, given number_1 and the total cycles.

I've been trying the maths and so far the closest I've got (by timing the result) is

total cycles=out of loop cycles + loop_1 cycles * number_1 * (loop_2 cycles/loop_1 cycles) * number_2

I realize this doesn't make sense, because the loop_1 cycles cancel out..

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What processor is that?  Unless you are on a really simple one,  timing will be difficult to predict.

Comment: figured it out.    total cycles=outofloopcycles + loop_1cycles*number_1 + loop_2cycles*number_2*number_1    really stupid when you think about it.    i'm using an MC9S08GT16A. think it does 20MHz.